# file choosing dialog not popping up

Tags: java, dialog, jfilechooser

I have a quick question about using `JFileChooser`. My understanding of the following code was that it would pop up a new file choosing dialog forever until the user clicked cancel or some error occurred. It appears, however, that the dialog only pops up the first time and the code fails second time through the loop. Oddly the program is still running while being stuck at

```
if (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null) != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
    return;
```

So.. what is going on in here? And how can I make this work?

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    while (true) {
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        if (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null) != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) return;
        // operation with the file
    }
}
```

Comment: This code works fine for me. If I select file I need to select next one, and so on until I press cancel or close dialog window.

Comment: Maybe it is not fileChooser which makes thread wait, but your `// operation with the file`.

Comment: It looks like you are running GUI code on the main thread, rather than the EDT. This will cause undefined behaviour which **will** result in bugs and (possibly) death.

Comment: @Pshemo Hmm I have just tried running it with all the operations part deleted, and still got the same result. I am using eclipse to run this; could it be the case that this is some bug within eclipse...?